# "Coat" vs. "jacket" in AE

Tags: american-english, word-usage

In some regions of the U.S., can the term "coat" be used to designate what other native speakers of other U.S. regions -- and from farther out -- would call a jacket?

> Please consider this Ngram: [source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=summer+coat%2Csummer+jacket%2Cspring+coat%2Cspring+jacket%2Cflannel+coat%2Cflannel+jacket%2Ccotton+coat%2Ccotton+jacket&year_start=1870&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csummer%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csummer%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspring%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspring%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflannel%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflannel%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccotton%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccotton%20jacket%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csummer%20coat%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Csummer%20jacket%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cspring%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspring%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflannel%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflannel%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccotton%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccotton%20jacket%3B%2Cc0)
>
> And this other one also...[source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heavy+coat%2Cheavy+jacket%2Cthick+coat%2Cthick+jacket%2Cwoolen+coat%2Cwoolen+jacket%2Cwool+jacket%2Cwool+coat%2Cwinter+jacket%2Cwinter+coat%2Ccashmere+jacket%2Ccashmere+coat&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheavy%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheavy%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthick%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthick%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoolen%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoolen%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwool%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwool%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwinter%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwinter%20coat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccashmere%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccashmere%20coat%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: There's a nice little discussion [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/139865/jacket-vs-coat-what-is-the-difference-length-or-thickness). In any case, the short answer to your question is: Yes.

Comment: (By the way, it's interesting to add "winter coat" and "winter jacket" to your [ngram](http://bit.ly/1jLqFK5)).

Comment: It's not really a local variance, just a variance in the exact kind of thing referred to.

Comment: Jackets are short, usually to the waist or just below it. Coats are usually longer. Also, jacket can match a skirt or trousers. Coats do not.

Comment: There are specific types of coat and jacket that may be long or short (a pea coat is fairly short, a smoking jacket can be longer, while a suit jacket is fairly short; a puffer jacket can be short but there are long versions, etc). Something that's part of a suit is normally a jacket, except for a tailcoat (a type of jacket with long tails). Often this reflects changing styles or other resemblances (is it jacket-like but longer; did it evolve from a type of jacket?) Not sure there's much regional although a Floridian's coat will likely be thinner than a Montanan's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coat is longer than a jacket - the jacket doesn't cover the hips and the coat does, or goes even farther to almost the knees.

Usually the insulation goes up to match, but not always.  When I lived in Chicago my winter coat was just a lined thick wool coat that went almost to the knees. By keeping the wind off the legs it was warmer than a down parka that left the legs exposed.

Comment: I consider my ski jacket to be a coat. If I had my tuxedo (which goes below the hips) lying next to my ski jacket and someone said bring me the coat, I'd expect them to bring the ski jacket.

Comment: Not if you were about to enter a ballroom you wouldn't.

Comment: I agree I wouldn't, because of the context. I would still think they made a mistake in using the word coat.

Comment: I don't see how this is a satisfactory answer to your OP. It does not really tell you whether the term "coat" be used to designate what other native speakers of other U.S. regions would call a jacket. Clearly, the phrase "coat and tie" shows that the designations are more complicated than this answer indicates. If Oldcat's reply answers your question, maybe you are asking a different question than the one you posted here.

Comment: Although M-W, for one, has the same definition for [sport coat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sport%20coat) and [sport jacket](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sport%20coat): "A man's **coat** that is like the top part of a suit but is less formal." And for *coat* M-W has "An outer garment worn on the upper body and **varying in length and style according to fashion and use**"

Comment: A smoking jacket can be knee-length, resembling a dressing gown. A car coat ends at mid-thigh, although older versions were longer (when cars were colder). A raincoat can be almost any length, as long as it keeps the rain off some part of your body; fur coat is often used for any outerwear made of fur even if it's short (although it's almost always warm, so coat=warmer may apply there).

Answer (score 9):

In my area (Wisconsin), a coat is a heavier outer garment ("winter coat") and a jacket is lighter ("spring jacket").

Of course, here in the northern part of the country we have very cold winters, and we need different words to describe these things.  For example: "Is it warm enough for a jacket, or do I need to bring a coat?"

Comment: Adding "winter coat" and "winter jacket" to the OP's [ngram](http://bit.ly/1jLqFK5) seems to support this.

Comment: Jason C The thing is the results in your ngram makes a lot of sense to me, as long as it sounds pretty obvious -- to my perspective -- that people in the height of winter when it's freezing cold outside tend to go more for long, warm coats that cover up most of their body rather than shorter -- yet warm -- mid waist or 3/4 waist jackets .;)

Comment: If a coat is by definition strictly a heavier outer garment and a jacket a lighter one, then it would seem redundant to add 'winter' to 'coat' or 'spring' to 'jacket'.

Comment: @sarah Redundant, yes, but it does add clarity when speaking to people that have a different understanding of the meaning of the words.

Comment: But note that one says 'ski jacket' not 'ski coat'. "Can you get me my coat out of the closet?" "Which one, your ski jacket?" "Yes, that one."

Comment: @Mitch, as per another answer, the ski jacket does not cover your hips, otherwise it would interfere with your skiing ability.

Comment: @hellion: are you saying a ski jacket is not a coat? I call them coats.

Comment: @Mitch, all jackets are coats but not all coats are jackets... I'm saying that "coat" is both a generic and a specific term; generic for "outer garment worn to protect from weather" and specific for "heavily-insulated outer garment extending below the hips".

Comment: @Hellion: well, I don't think a blazer (a sports jacket) or wind breaker (another kind of jacket) are coats.

Comment: @Ben Miller Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I was saying that the maybe the fact that you would add "winter" to "coat" means that you could also add "spring" or "fall" to it, therefore taking away from a clear definition of "coat" as "a heavier outer garment."

Comment: @sarah My point was that, where I'm from, saying "coat" without qualifiers implies a heavy garment suitable for winter temperatures.  Maybe I could say "spring coat," if I wanted to refer to something else, but simply saying "coat" implies "winter coat."

Comment: @Ben Miller At any rate, I don't see how your answer is a satisfactory answer to the question, "In some regions of the U.S., can the term "coat" be used to designate what other native speakers of other U.S. regions -- and from farther out -- would call a jacket?" It seems it ought to be a comment, not an answer. Then again, the answer the OP chose seems no better.

Answer (score 4):

(AmE here)

NG, I don't think it's due to 'dialect'. In Ame, *coat* usually refers to a longer outergarment whereas *jacket* usually refers to a shorter one.

Any jacket can be considered a [coat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coat) (an outer piece of clothing that can be long or short and that is worn to keep warm or dry) but not every coat can be considered a [jacket](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jacket) (a garment for the upper body *usually* having a front opening, collar, lapels, sleeves, and pockets) which has a much more restrictive definition, and can refer not only to short outerwear, but the upper garment in a suit, or anything like it.

Comment: I also tend to differentiate by level of insulation-  a coat usually will keep you warmer than a jacket:  "*How cold is it outside?  Do I need my coat?  Or can I just wear my jacket?*"

Comment: I don't know, I think it is somewhat regional, or at least, your description does not agree with my experiences. Personally, I rarely use the term "jacket", and the people I usually communicate with seem to be similar. "Where's your coat?" "Should I wear my coat?" "Put your coat on!" are always used, at least where I'm from, to generally mean any sleeved garment you'd wear in a casual setting to protect yourself from cold. I have a friend from southern California though who always says "jacket" (I've spent my life in Pennsylvania and New York). It feels more like a soda vs. pop thing to me.

Comment: (I've also noticed that my grandparents use "jacket", perhaps there is a generational aspect, too? Maybe more like *garbage/trash vs. rubbish* or *dinner vs. supper* than *soda vs. pop*). The discussion [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/139865/jacket-vs-coat-what-is-the-difference-length-or-thickness) seems to support the notion that it's fairly arbitrary, generally driven by local habits.

Comment: @JasonC - those are great examples. You might be right. I agree with Jim, though. Coat is warmer.

Comment: It seems that there are regional differences in usage, but your answer is generally a pretty good one. I'd say that most jackets could also serve as coats, but not all. For instance, I have some very lightweight jackets that I would never call a coat.

Comment: There is also the usage of coat to refer to a jacket as in "coat and tie," or "suit coat." I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_(clothing)#Coats.2C_jackets_and_overcoats) Coats, jackets and overcoats section of the Wikipdia entry for 'coat' very good. It begins, "In the early nineteenth century, coats were divided into under-coats and overcoats. The term under-coat is now archaic but denoted the fact that the word coat could be both the outermost layer for outdoor wear (overcoat) or the coat worn under that (under-coat)."